# How exactly are microservices implemented?

Tags: spring-boot, docker, spring-mvc, amazon-ec2

I'm playing around with Docker and deploying microservices to an EC2 instance. I'm going through several tutorials, but every one of them deploys just one microservice and that's it. For example, many tutorials implement some simple controller such as

```
@RestController
public class LogicOneController {

    @GetMapping
    @RequestMapping("/logic_one")
    public String entry() {
        return "LogicOneController stuff";
    }
}
```

in a spring boot app. I can access this api from ec2 such as `www.my-ec2-instance/logic_one`. But the point of using microservices is to have many other services so how do I go about adding another one? Let's say I have another set of apis `LogicTwoController`.

Am I supposed to deploy this to another spring boot app? If this is the case, then I suppose we just run multiple containers on the same ec2 instance and access it via `www.my-ec2-instance/logic_two` and `www.my-ec2-instance/logic_three` and so on. Is this the right idea?

Comment: If you're intending on running many services/containers on a machine(s) you'll need some sort of container/task/service orchestration. There are a few industry leading solutions for docker like Kubernetes & nomad (I'm a big fan of nomad) that will manage the orchestration and deployment of 100's to 1000's of docker containers/services on a cluster

Answer (score 1):

Microservices should not split by logic_one/two/three. It's sud separate by the business domain which may work in independent, There's much logic in a domain of business.
Back to e-commerce design. Assume that few kind of domain like (login/auth, user, order, shipping).
So each domain may consider as 1 module/domain

- Login/auth => the service has a responsibility to manage login token, authorization
- User => the service manages all user profile
- Order => the service where user can create/execute/cancel... an order
- Shipping => the service where you can update/manage the status of shipping with 3rd party...

So, if you have only logic_1, logic_2,... It's 1 service/ 1 module. Above just an example, an actual microservice system is split quite small domain.

- a different in Microservice system is, the client(mobile/web...) only communitate with a service call API-GateWay instead of touch to core services (login/auth, user, order, shipping...) directly. It's like 1-stop service lol

Note: An application not using/apply Microservices pattern does not mean that that is not a good design.

Comment: Maybe my api example was not crafted well, but wouldn't different api's contain very different business purposes? Eg a controller that handled a consumer's information vs a controller that handled a product's information would require separate containers right?